# 400 Bad Request to access WCF API over HTTPS

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

Can someone please point me out what's wrong with this service configuration in `web.config`. I want to access this over `HTTPS`.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="TransportSecurity">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
      <endpoint  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
        <enableWebScript/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false">
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have enabled `SSL` using Test Certificates on `IIS7`. The `Service1.svc` is accessible without any error and I am getting `200 OK Response` when accessed through a `.NET` Console client application. But I am getting `400 Bad Request` while accessing the `api` defined in the service. The same api is working fine when used with HTTP configuration.